# Contact form using php jquery and html 5 from a template

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

so that's the Html page integrated with CSS the form in PHP and the call out to js script.

```
<section class="contact-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-none d-sm-block mb-5 pb-4"></div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="contact-title">Inoltra qui la tua richiesta</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Inserisci il Messaggio'" placeholder="Inserisci il Messaggio"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Nome'" placeholder="Nome">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Inserisci l'indirizzo mail'" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Inserisci Oggetto'" placeholder="Inserisci Oggetto">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Invia</button>
                            <br><br>Questo sito è protetto dal sistema antispam Google Recaptcha.
                            <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> e <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Termini di servizio</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

this is the contact form in the PHP

```
<?php

$to = " infoessebi-ingegneria@gmail.com";
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
$cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

$headers = "From: $from";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$subject = "You have a new message from Site.";

$logo = 'img/logo.png';
$link = '#';

$body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
$body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
$body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
$body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
$body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
$body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
$body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
$body .= "</tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
$body .= "</tbody></table>";
$body .= "</body></html>";

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

and here we have the .js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($) {
    "use strict";


jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
}, "type the correct answer -_-");

// validate contactForm form
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            subject: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            number: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 20
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Campo richiesto",
                minlength: "il tuo nome deve consistere in almeno 2 caratteri"
            },
            subject: {
                required: "Campo richiesto",
                minlength: "il tuo oggetti deve avere almeno 4 caratteri"
            },
            number: {
                required: "come on, you have a number, don't you?",
                minlength: "your Number must consist of at least 5 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Campo richiesto"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Campo richiesto",
                minlength: "mi spiace ma non hai scritto un messaggio abbastanza lungo"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"contact_process.php",
                success: function() {
                    $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn()
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#success').modal('show');
                    })
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                        $('#error').fadeIn()
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#error').modal('show');
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
    
})(jQuery)
})
```

my question is why when all uploaded seems that nothing is working? any clue?

pls help i reviewed the code with my tiny knowledge but i can't find the error.

Comment: what is not working? The PHP that handles the processing or the javascript? What debugging have you done?

Comment: i don't know what is not working cause when i try to see what is going wrong the debug software seems  all ok so i'm wondering if i missing something somewhere or i have problems with my server

Comment: what debug software do you mean exactly? For example, have you used the Developer Tools in your browser to check for Console errors and problems with the AJAX? And what do you mean by "nothing is working", precisely? Describe clearly what happens when you load the page. Are you able to see the form? Are you able to enter text and submit? What happens when you try to submit? Does the validation work? Does it try to submit the form? Does the data reach the PHP. I note also that your PHP code doesn't bother to check whether `mail()` has succeeded or not.

Comment: yes i used the console from chrome to see if all script in the page were running fine and it seems ok . But i repeat i'm totally a noob in php and jscript so if you have suggestion they are deeply appreciated

Comment: You need to break the process down into all the small steps involved, and check each one in order to see if it's happening correctly or not. Then you can start to work out where things are going wrong, and that will give you some chance of fixing it. We can't really tell easily just by reading the code.

Comment: basically all the controls about the contact box are working but when i try to submit the form nothing happens
about this 
"PHP code doesn't bother to check whether mail() has succeeded or not."
check is in the js file

Comment: "check is in the js file"...how exactly? PHP doesn't output the `$send` variable so there is no way for the JS to check it. And anyway there is no JS code which even attempts to check it.

Comment: "when i try to submit the form nothing happens"...this suggests either the JavaScript failed (so either you have a Console error, or your script isn't bound to the event properly), or the AJAX called failed (in which again there's often a console error, or at the very least you can see something in the browser's Network tool which would indicate what happened with the call to contact_process.php). "nothing happens" isn't a useful description of the problem though - more than likely, _something_ happened, you just haven't been able to observe it yet.

Comment: i will try to do some more tests in the meantime thanks for the help !

Comment: Fit the code properly in the code tag. Some grammar corrections.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code, you should try. Just change the variables

Here is my simple HTML contact form with CSS like yours

```
<div class="contact-form">
            <h4 class="title-top-w3">Get in touch<span>|</span></h4>
            <h5 class="title-main-w3ls">Contact Me</h5>
            
            <div class="alert" id="status"></div>
            
                <div class="col-md-6 styled-input-w3-agile">
                    <input type="text" name="Full Name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 styled-input-w3-agile">
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            <div class="styled-input-w3-agile">
                    <input type="phone" name="" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" required="">
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                <div class="styled-input-w3-agile">
                    <input type="text" name="Subject" id="title" placeholder="Enter the discussion title" required="">
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                <div class="styled-input-w3-agile textarea-grid">
                    <textarea name="Message"  id="message" placeholder="Write your message" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send Message">
                
        </div>
```

JQuery Ajax-Call to handle the HTML IDS and pass them into sendmail.php
I named it sendmail.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#send").on('click', function(e){
        
        $("#send").text('Please Wait..');
        $("#send").attr('disabled', true);
        
        $.ajax({
                url: "js/sendmail.php",
            method:"POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                data:{
                    name:$("#name").val(),
                    email:$("#email").val(),
                    phone:$("#phone").val(),
                    title:$("#title").val(),
                    message:$("#message").val()
                },
                success:function(res){
                    $("#send").text('Send Message');
                    $("#send").attr('disabled', false);
                    if (res == 1){
                        $("#status").html('Message Sent Successfully');
                    }else if(res == 0){
                        $("#status").html('Message Failed');
                    }else if(res == 2){
                        $("#status").html('Empty Fields Detected.');
                    }else if(res == 3){
                        $("#status").html('Invalid Email Address.');
                    }
                    
                },
                error: function(err){
                    
                    $('#status').html( "Network Connection Error");
                }
                });
    
        
    });
    
    });
```

Here is sendmail.php where the Sendmail class performs the function getMailStatus which sends all your parameters into the mail() function after validation and returns $status which is used in the JQuery

```
  <?php
    

class Sendmail{
    
function getMailStatus(){
    //Check For Submit
        $status = '';
        //Get Form Data
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
        $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                $status = '3';
            } else {
                // Passed
                // Recipient Email
                $toEmail = 'omotayotemi47@gmail.com';
                $subject = ''.$title;
                $body = '<h2>Contact Request</h2>
                    <h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p>
                    <h4>Phone Number</h4><p>'.$phone.'</p>
                    <h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p>
                    <h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p>
                    ';

                //Email Headers
                $headers ="MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\r\n";
                $headers .="Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

                // Additional Headers
                $headers .= "From: " .$name. "<".$email.">". "\r\n";

                if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                    // Email Sent
                    $status = '1';
                } else {
                    //Failed
                    $status = '2';
                }
            }
        
    return $status;
}
    
}
        
$test = new Sendmail();
    echo $test->getMailStatus();
?>
```

Comment: Please explain **what** you've changed, and **why** - this helps others to learn from your answer

Comment: There's too much code here for it to go without _any_ explanation. A useful answer actually comments on the code and explains it. Otherwise you're expecting people to spot and understand the significant parts of it themselves, which, if they're coming here with a related problem in the first place, is likely to be difficult for them. Also it's time-consuming to do that, whereas you, who already knows the code could make it easy to understand. The easier and more useful your answer is, the more upvotes it will attract.

Comment: I have edited the code and explained briefly what happens at each stage. this is a working code I am using a little study after implementing and you are on your way. i lazily had to use my own variables which are relative to his. thanks